# Page_Error does not show Unhandled Exception in WebMethod call by Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, webforms

Im new to C# ASP.net. I use Monodevelop in Ubuntu to create a simple WebForm.

Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Exception Ex = Server.GetLastError();
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
    }


    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string TestUnhandledException()
    {
        throw new Exception("abc");
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MyFirstWebForm.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>
    <script>
        function Test() {
            PageMethods.TestUnhandledException(OnSuccessCallback, OnFailureCallback);
        }

        function OnSuccessCallback(res) {}
        function OnFailureCallback() {}
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id='form1' runat='server'>
        <asp:scriptmanager enablepagemethods="true" id="scpt" runat="server"> </asp:scriptmanager>
        <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Initialize" OnClientClick='Test();return false;'/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The method TestUnhandledException() works fine, but as I debug, there is no exception message show and Page_Error() never runs.

Do I miss something ? How should I log the unhandled exception in ASP.NET webform ? I appreciate any help.

Update: The exception throw by Page_Load is caught by Page_Error but the one thrown by [WebMethod] does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is not simple to catch unhandled exception thrown by WebMethod.
From this [post](http://beyondthispoint.blogspot.de/2008/04/managing-unhandled-exceptions-in-aspnet.html):

> you can't just add a few lines of code to the Global.aspx.cs file in
>   the Application_Error event handler method to log unhandled exceptions
>   because the ASP.NET Web Services pipeline bypasses this event so it
>   can return all the exceptions back to the caller.

So probably the most simple way is to surround the method with try-catch block as shown in the post

Answer (score 0):

Did you check inner Exception ?. your exception message should be in there

Comment: The problem is as I debug, Page_Error() never runs in the first place